# Python selenium lib not installing on windows

Tags: python, windows-7, selenium

Trying to install Selenium's python library on a windows 7 computer:

I got this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 03/31/11 11:44:21
Downloading/unpacking selenium
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py", line 127, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 936, in prepare_files
    location = req_to_install.build_location(self.build_dir, not self.is_download)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 147, in build_location
    _make_build_dir(build_dir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-0.8.3-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line 1177, in _make_build_dir
    os.makedirs(build_dir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\build'
```

Comment: Maybe start `cmd` with administrative privileges?

Answer (score 4):

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\build'
```

Well, this line says that you don't have access to `C:\Windows\System32\`. That usually occurs  you're not an administrator.

Try running `pip` from the administrator account:

1. Press the Windows Logo Thing (technical name for it).
2. Type in "**cmd**".
3. Right-click "**cmd.exe**" and click "**Run as administrator**".
4. Bear with UAC.
5. *Now* try running `pip`.

Comment: Best and only answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install from a directory that you have access to:

```
pushd %USERPROFILE%
pip install selenium
```

Alternatively, you may get the pre-built package [via PyPM](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/selenium/).